# How to convert element in string into it's own string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char

```
string line = "testtesttest";
string whole = line[i];
```

Why doesn't this code work? I need to do this conversion so I can use strcmp so I can compare the string element to an array of chars

```
char symbols[3][3] = {'--', '*-', '-*'};
```

I was trying to do this

```
if (strcmp(line[i],symbols[j]) == 1)
```

but apparently `line[i]` doesn't count as a string, so I think converting `line[i]` to a string somehow would be the best course of action. I have tried multiple other conversions to find a way to compare an element of a `string[i]` to each char '`symbol` but nothing is working for me. I have tried `strcpy` and a bunch more things and I am getting frustrated, any help is appreciated.

Comment: [`string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) does what you want. Or simply write `if (line[i] == symbols[j])`.

Comment: You seem to have multiple misconceptions here; your probably better off scrapping what you've written and rethinking it from scratch. Or at least ask a question about what you're trying to do, rather than trying to patch up the problems with how you've tried to do it.

Comment: Note that `'--'` is not a C-string but a multibyte character literal, and that `strcmp`, while not the appropriate tool here, returns zero for a match.

Answer (score 1):

See the list of `std::string` constructors: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

You can make a string containing a single character from another string like this:

```
string whole(1, line[i]);
```

Or like this:

```
string whole(line, i, 1);
```

In the first case if you change `1` to a larger number, you will get that many copies of a single character.  In the second case you will get a longer substring.